# Remove random subset of an array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, random

I have an array  `a = array([ [x1,x2,...,xn], [y1,y2,...,yn]])` so `a.shape=(2,n)`. Is there a quick way to obtain a random subset of this array, i.e. an array of the form `r = array([ [xi1,xi2,...,xip], [yi1,yi2,...,yip]])` ?

Comment: can you please also include some of the code you tried?

Comment: I've tried for example ```a0 = np.random.choice(a[0], size=p, replace=False)
a1 = np.array([a[1][a0.tolist().index(value)] for value in a0])
a = np.vstack((a0,a1))```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.choice` to mask the columns and index away:

```
idx = np.random.choice([True,False], replace=True, size=a.shape[1],
                       p=[0.7,0.3]          # keep approx. 70% of columns
                      )
a[:, idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

First get some random indexes:

```
i=np.random.randint(2, size=a.shape[1])
```

Then keep only these dimensions:

```
b=a[:,np.where(i==1)]
```

Example:

```
>>> a
array([[1. , 2. , 3. , 4. , 5. , 6. , 7. ],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]])
>>> i=np.random.randint(2, size=a.shape[1])
>>> i
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
>>> a[:,np.where(i==1)]
array([[[3. , 4. , 5. , 6. ]],

       [[0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]]])
```